# Dockerfile with Rust code - what should be the correct WORKDIR

Tags: docker, rust, dockerfile

I want to create a Dockerfile which will run my Rust code, however, I think I'm doing something wrong with the WORKDIR.

My Rust code has the following structure:

```
my_app
├── Dockerfile
├── code
│   ├── Cargo.lock
│   ├── Cargo.toml
│   ├── app1
│   │   ├── Cargo.toml
│   │   ├── benches
│   │   └── src
│   ├── app2
│   │   ├── Cargo.toml
│   │   ├── benches
│   │   └── src
│   └── target
└── dependency_code
    ├── Cargo.toml
    └── src
```

The main Cargo.toml is defined as:

```
[profile.release]
panic = "abort"
opt-level = "s"
overflow-checks = true

[profile.dev]
panic = "abort"

[workspace]

resolver = "2"
members = ['app1', 'app2']
```

and `dependecy_code` is a custom code for one of the dependency packages I use in both app1 and app2, specified in their `app1/Cargo.toml` and `app2/Cargo.toml` as

```
[dependencies]
bls12_381 = { path = "../../dependecy_code", default-features = false}
```

My `Dockerfile` is defined as

```
# Use a base image with the 1.66.1 version of Rust installed
FROM rust:1.66.1

# Set the working directory in the container
WORKDIR /my_app/code

# Copy the local application code into the container
COPY . .

# Build the Rust application
RUN cargo build --release
```

However, when I try to run it as `docker build -t my-rust-app .` I get the following error:

```
[+] Building 0.9s (8/8) FINISHED
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                            0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                                              0.0s
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                         0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 351B                                                                                                                                         0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/rust:1.66.1                                                                                                               0.5s
 => [1/4] FROM docker.io/library/rust:1.66.1@sha256:23b7815cff2b70148cc7fa732825a5384a347b38217f162525c8f86610a6ae35                                                         0.0s
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                                                                            0.2s
 => => transferring context: 827.43kB                                                                                                                                        0.2s
 => CACHED [2/4] WORKDIR /my_app/code                                                                                                                               0.0s
 => CACHED [3/4] COPY . .                                                                                                                                                    0.0s
 => ERROR [4/4] RUN cargo build --release                                                                                                                                    0.2s
------
 > [4/4] RUN cargo build --release:
#0 0.180 error: could not find `Cargo.toml` in `/my_app/code` or any parent directory
------
Dockerfile:11
--------------------
   9 |
  10 |     # Build the Rust application
  11 | >>> RUN cargo build --release
  12 |
  13 |
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c cargo build --release" did not complete successfully: exit code: 101
```

I tried to put the `Dockerfile` in the `code` folder, but then the docker has an issue with loading the `failed to load manifest for dependency dependency_code`.
Can someone guide me on how I should fix the Dockerfile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you `COPY . .`, you are copying everything in the `my_app` directory to your WORKDIR, `/my_app/code`.  This results in your `cargo.toml` file having the path of `/my_app/code/code/Cargo.toml`, and docker is running the `cargo build --release` in the workdir `/my_app/code` directory where there is no Cargo.toml file.

I'd recommend changing workdir to `/my_app`, and your run command to  `cargo build --release --manifest-path code/Cargo.toml` or something along those lines to reflect that the Cargo.toml is not in the same directory as WORKDIR

Comment: If I read the directory tree in the question correctly, there _is_ a `Cargo.toml` file at the top level, so I don't think this is the reason.

Comment: I think the directory tree was confusing, and you are actually right. Since the OP didn't reply to a question, I went ahead and replaced the tree with an unambiguous version.